# The relationship '' was not loaded because the type '' is not available

Tags: .net, entity-framework, ef-code-first

recently i have been learning entity framework, by creating restful server for the midcore mobile game. To start with i have problem which is exactly the same as title of the question.

Already i have 2 projects in my solution first is for repository it is including my entities, functionallity of the server and all around this. Second one is for web app with models.

And i have been working on clearing out better database structure. But after refactoring, i have done some mistake and now i'm receiving this error:

> "exceptionMessage": "Schema specified is not valid. Errors: The relationship 'Server.Character_WeaponItem' was not loaded because the type 'Server.Item' is not available."

I just can't figure out what i'm doing wrong. Please give me some description of this so i will understand better the problem.

My structures :

Item Entity:

```
namespace Server
{
    public class Item
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int UserId { get; set; }
        public int ItemTemplateId{ get; set; }
        public int Level { get; set; }
        public int LevelProgress { get; set; }
        public int Count { get; set; }

        public User User { get; set; }
        public ItemTemplate ItemTemplate { get; set; }
        public Rune RuneSlotOne { get; set; }
        public Rune RuneSlotTwo { get; set; }
        public Rune RuneSlotThree { get; set; }
        public Character Owner { get; set; }

    }
}
```

Character Entity:

```
namespace Server
{
    public class Character
    {

        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int UserId { get; set; }
        public int CharacterTemplateId { get; set; }
        public int Level { get; set; }
        public int LevelProgress { get; set; }

        public User User { get; set; }
        public CharacterTemplate CharacterTemplate { get; set; }
        public Item WeaponItem { get; set; }
        public Item AdditionalItem { get; set; }

     }
}
```

And now Mappers for them :

```
namespace Server.Mappers
{
public class CharacterMapper : EntityTypeConfiguration<Character>
{
    public CharacterMapper()
    {
        HasKey(c => c.Id);
        Property(c => c.Id).IsRequired();
        Property(c => c.Id).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);

        HasRequired(c => c.User).WithMany(u => u.Characters).HasForeignKey(c => c.UserId);
        HasRequired(t => t.CharacterTemplate).WithMany(c => c.Characters).HasForeignKey(t => t.CharacterTemplateId);

        HasOptional(r => r.WeaponItem)
            .WithOptionalDependent(item => item.Owner)
            .Map(map=>map.MapKey("WeaponId"));

        HasOptional(r => r.AdditionalItem)
            .WithOptionalDependent(item => item.Owner)
            .Map(configuration => configuration.MapKey("AdditionalItemId"));

    }
}
}
```

And last item mapper :

```
public class ItemMapper : EntityTypeConfiguration<Item>
{
    public ItemMapper()
    {
        HasKey(i => i.Id);
        Property(i => i.Id).IsRequired();
        Property(i => i.Id).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);

        HasRequired(i => i.User).WithMany(i => i.Items).HasForeignKey(i => i.UserId);

        HasRequired(i => i.ItemTemplate).WithMany(i => i.Items).HasForeignKey(i => i.ItemTemplateId);

        Property(i => i.Count).IsOptional();

        Property(i => i.Level).IsRequired();

        Property(i => i.LevelProgress).IsRequired();

        HasOptional(i => i.RuneSlotOne)
            .WithOptionalDependent(rune => rune.ItemOwner)
            .Map(configuration => configuration.MapKey("RuneOneId"));

        HasOptional(i => i.RuneSlotTwo)
            .WithOptionalDependent(rune => rune.ItemOwner)
            .Map(configuration => configuration.MapKey("RuneTwoId"));

        HasOptional(i => i.RuneSlotThree)
            .WithOptionalDependent(rune => rune.ItemOwner)
            .Map(configuration => configuration.MapKey("RuneThreeId"));


    }
}
```

Ohh and i was searching for related posts, but there are so many with the same message that i don't know how to start look for the problem.

Answer (score 0):

So i have been thinking about the ef code first problem but that was the relationship design problem.

Character can have items ( for my example can have two items) but item can be attached or not. So Character have to got navigation for its items and item must have optional place for character owner.

The solution is :

```
public class ItemMapper : EntityTypeConfiguration<Item>
{
    public ItemMapper()
    {
        HasKey(i => i.Id);
        Property(i => i.Id).IsRequired();
        Property(i => i.Id).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);

        HasRequired(i => i.User).WithMany(i => i.Items).HasForeignKey(i => i.UserId);

        HasRequired(i => i.ItemTemplate).WithMany(i => i.Items).HasForeignKey(i => i.ItemTemplateId);

        Property(i => i.Count).IsOptional();

        Property(i => i.Level).IsRequired();

        Property(i => i.LevelProgress).IsRequired();

        HasOptional(item => item.Owner)
            .WithMany(character => character.Items)
            .Map(configuration => configuration.MapKey("OwnerId"));

    }
}
```

Then Item :

```
public class Item
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public int ItemTemplateId{ get; set; }
    public int Level { get; set; }
    public int LevelProgress { get; set; }
    public int Count { get; set; }

    public User User { get; set; }
    public ItemTemplate ItemTemplate { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Rune> RuneSlots { get; set; } 
    public Character Owner { get; set; }

}
```

And Character Scripts :

```
public class CharacterMapper : EntityTypeConfiguration<Character>
{
    public CharacterMapper()
    {
        HasKey(c => c.Id);
        Property(c => c.Id).IsRequired();
        Property(c => c.Id).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);

        HasRequired(c => c.User).WithMany(u => u.Characters).HasForeignKey(c => c.UserId);
        HasRequired(t => t.CharacterTemplate).WithMany(c => c.Characters).HasForeignKey(t => t.CharacterTemplateId);


    }
}
```

Character :

```
public class Character
{
    public Character()
    {
        Items = new List<Item>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public int CharacterTemplateId { get; set; }
    public int Level { get; set; }
    public int LevelProgress { get; set; }

    public User User { get; set; }
    public CharacterTemplate CharacterTemplate { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Item> Items { get; set; } 


}
```